# Is it possible to add a template to a theme in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, template

Current situation: I have created a **custom theme** that extends from the **Magento blank** theme.

Requirement: I need to add a section that contains some small images to the footer for the whole site.

Possible solution: keeping with Magento's modular templates, add a template, extend the default.xml layout which references the template.

I have tried to add the template as follows:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
<block name="footer.advisories" 
       class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
       template="Extending_theme::html/footer_advisories.phtml" />

</referenceContainer>
```

This produces an invalid template error.

I have also tried `template="html/footer_advisories.phtml"`.

My question is, is it possible to create a template in a theme? If so, how can i reference it? If not, have you any suggestions how I might do this?

I was thinking about creating a custom module, but this seems overkill for what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you in advance, Andy

Comment: please try Extending_theme to Extending_Theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out as follows.

I was extending a Magento_Theme layout, and the new template was in the same Magento_Theme folder, I can reference it using `template="Magento_Theme::html/footer_advisories.phtml"`.

Please let me know if anyone needs further explanation.